# Laravel: как конвертировать api resources в string или array/json?

Tags: php, laravel

Читаю статью https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources , но там все выводы - это в реквест, т.е. вывод json на экран.

Но если мне нужно записать данные в файл или в бд - мне нужна строка или хотя бы array/json.

Как мне получить сухие данные или результирующую строку из Laravel api resources?

Comment: Сухие данные получаются через метод toArray, насчёт остального не совсем понятно что именно вам нужно.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Там есть toArray - но у ресурса он совсем другой и отвечает за другое.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел два варианта решения:

1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52539291/laravel-how-to-convert-api-resource-to-array-recursively

```
    $preorder = Preorder::find(1); 
    $jsonResponse = (new PreorderResource($preorder->load('driver')))->toResponse(app('request'));

    echo $jsonResponse->getData();
```

2) `$apiRecourceCollection->collection->map->resolve()->toJson();`